# Unity3d OnTriggerEnter2D not firing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

I'm currently trying to make a Unity3d (Or 2D in this case) Platformer tech demo.
While working on the demo I ran into a bit of a snag because I want my Player object to be able to go up slopes, but if I apply gravity while the Player object is on the ground it will not be able to go up slopes, even if it can go down them. My solution was to turn off gravity while the PLayer object was touching the ground, and turn it back on when it wasn't. I did this by using the functions `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` to turn the gravity off, and `void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)` to turn it back on.

This did not work, so I played with it a bit and thought of the idea to give the ground, and Player object "Trigger Boxes" which are unseen child Cube objects that have a Collider marked as a Trigger. So now I am using the function `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)` to turn the gravity off, and `void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)` to turn it back on. But this also does not work. Below is my code, first is the Player object's main script, and after that is the Player object's "TriggerBox" and after that will be images to show how my objects are setup in Unity.

The result: The Player class currently does not collide with the ground, and falls through it to infinity.

What I want: The player to collide with the ground, and the player's TriggerBox to collide with the ground's "TriggerBox" and turn off the Player's gravity.

Notes: I've tried giving the players, and ground RigidBody2Ds. The player collides with the ground and gets jittery, and does not trigger the gravity turn-off, and the ground falls on contact with the player when the ground has the RigidBody2D. It is unknown what triggers, as the ground falls right under the player.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterController controller;
    private float speed = 0.004f;
    private float fallSpeed = 0.01f;
    private Vector3 tempPos;

    bool onGround = false;

    public void setOnGround(bool b){ onGround = b; }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        tempPos = Vector3.zero;

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) tempPos.y -= speed;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) tempPos.y += speed;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) tempPos.x -= speed;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) tempPos.x += speed;

        RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y), new Vector2(0, -1), 0.2f);
        float fallDist = -fallSpeed;

        if(hits.Length > 1){
            Vector3 temp3Norm = new Vector3(hits[1].normal.x, hits[1].normal.y, 0);
            Vector3 temp3Pos = new Vector3(tempPos.x, tempPos.y, 0);

            temp3Pos = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, temp3Norm) * temp3Pos;

            tempPos = new Vector2(temp3Pos.x, temp3Pos.y);
        }

        if(!onGround) tempPos.y = fallDist;



        transform.Translate(tempPos);
    }

}
```

Next the TriggerBox:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerTriggerBox : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerControls playerControls;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //playerControls = gameOGetComponent<PlayerControls>();
        if(playerControls == null) Debug.Log("playerControls IS NULL IN PlayerTriggerBox!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        playerControls.setOnGround(true);
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collision2D collision){
        playerControls.setOnGround(false);
    }
}
```

-As for the images for my setup-

The player's setup: [image]
The player's TriggerBox setup: [image]
The ground's setup: [image]
The ground's TriggerBox setup: [image]

Thank you for your time reading this, and hopefully for your help.

Comment: Did you try to activate the is trigger option on the player?

Comment: Well, you don't have to turn the gravity off to mive the character, you just have to apply a force strong enough to move the object mass.